# SQL Scripted Restore Using With Move - With File & With

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to script a restore of one of our databases and I need to know the correct syntax for using the with file and with move commands

So far I have:

```
   RESTORE DATABASE Test
   FROM DISK = 'E:\Test_db_BASELINE.BAK'
   WITH FILE = 1
   WITH MOVE 'Test_dat' TO 'C:\MSSQL\v2_Data\Test_Data.MDF',
        MOVE 'Test_log' TO 'C:\MSSQL\v2_Data\Test_Log.LDF', REPLACE
```

I get syntax error any ideas?

to put into context I am trying to execute the below to automate a restore where the bak file has a timestamped naming convention:

```
      --==CHECK IF DB EXISTS IF IT DOES DROP IT

 USE [master]
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases where name='SlotLookup')
 DROP DATABASE [SlotLookup]


 --==START THE RESTORE PROCESS
 DECLARE @FileName varchar(255), @PathToBackup varchar(255), @RestoreFilePath varchar(1000)

 DECLARE @Files TABLE (subdirectory varchar(255), depth int, [file] int)

 SET NOCOUNT ON

--==SET THE FILEPATH
 SET @PathToBackup = 'path'

 --insert into our memory table using dirtree and a single file level
 INSERT INTO @Files
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_DirTree @PathToBackup,1,1

 SELECT TOP 1 
    @FileName = [subdirectory]
 FROM 
    @Files
 WHERE
    -- get where it is a file
    [file] = 1
 AND 
 --==FIND THE LOGICAL NAME OF THE BAK FILE FROM THE CHRONILOGICALLY ORDERED LIST   
    subdirectory LIKE '%.bak'
 ORDER BY
    -- order descending so newest file will be first by naming convention
    subdirectory DESC

IF LEFT(REVERSE(@PathToBackup), 1) != '\'
BEGIN
    SET @PathToBackup = @PathToBackup + '\'
END

SET @RestoreFilePath = @PathToBackup + @FileName

SELECT @RestoreFilePath

--===BEGIN THE RESTORE TO THE DESIGNATED SERVER
RESTORE DATABASE [SlotLookup] 
FROM DISK = @RestoreFilePath
FILE = 1
WITH MOVE 'SlotLookup' TO 'path\SlotLookup.mdf',
MOVE 'SlotLookup_log' TO 'path\SlotLookup_log.ldf'
```

get syntax error
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FILE'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 49

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the error message is:  get syntax error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FILE'. Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of a restore backup script with move is like this following:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorksCopy] FROM DISK = 'c:\mssql\backup\[...]\Backup.bak' 
WITH CHECKSUM, 
MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Data' TO 'c:\mssql\data\[...]\AdventureWorksCopy_Data.mdf', 
MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Log' TO 'c:\mssql\log\[...]\AdventureWorksCopy_Log.ldf', 
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

What syntax error do you get?
Please include it in the questions